# No suggest in Xcode after importing MobileCoreServices

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

```
import UIKit
import CoreSpotlight
import MobileCoreServices
```

I imported this frameworks to Xcode, but I don't see a suggest while typing in this moment bellow:

```
let item = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTType //here I have no suggests/list with suggestions.
        item.title = listToDo[indexPath.item]["title"]
        item.contentDescription = listToDo[indexPath.item]["state"]
```

Can somebody tell me why? (suggest from CoreSpotlight is ok)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Xcode just stops giving suggestions. Clean the build folder and/or restarting usually solves the problem.